# Will version 5 Introduce native transport for linux using epoll ET?

Tags: netty

I noticed that version 4 introduce Native epoll edge-triggered transport.

So will version 5 introduce this feature as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is included in 4.x and 5.x . So yes ;)

Comment: Great! I am looking forward to using it in version 5 since i am still in Alpha.